# Adding values in a grouped col

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two postgress tables Users (userId, city,email) and Purchase(userId,ItemId,name,amount) I want to run a query to give me the total items purchased by a userId and to give me the total  amount spent by a user. How can I get those results?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `count()`, `sum()` functions and `group by`. Try:

```
select u.userID, count(p.ItemID) as TotalItemsPurchased, sum(p.amount) as TotalAmountSpent
from Users u
inner join Purchase p on p.userID = u.userID
group by u.userID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select couserID, count(p.ItemID) as "TotalItemsPurchased", sum(p.amount) as "TotalAmountSpent" from Users u 
inner join Purchase p on p.userId = u.userId
group by userID
```

Comment: change  couserID to userId

Comment: @Shekhar-How can I modify the query if im looking for certain item ids?

Comment: certain ItemIds of user?

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about users who have made purchases, you do not need a `join`:

```
select p.user_id, count(*), sum(p.amount)
from purchases p
group by p.user_id;
```

If you do care about users who have made no purchases as well, use `left join`:

```
select u.user_id, count(p.user_id), sum(p.amount)
from users u left join
     purchases p
     on u.user_id = p.user_id
group by u.user_id;
```